# error module java.base does not "opens java.util" to unnamed module

Tags: mysql, netbeans

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Este es el error**

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make field transient java.util.Set java.util.AbstractMap.keySet accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.util" to unnamed module @228baf96

Comment: Codigo y errores como texto, no como imagenes.

Comment: tengo el mismo problema, si pudo solucionar?

Comment: tal vez les ayude mi respuesta: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/607932/342