# Desplegar war con jenkins dentro de wildfly (Jboss)

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, jboss, wildfly

Tengo mi war en el workspace de jenkins y quiero desplegarlo en un WildFly(Jboss) mediante un pipeline aunque de lo malo también valdría realizarlo como estilo libre pero el wild fly en estilo libre me da este error:

> FATAL: Could not initialize class
> org.wildfly.security.manager.WildFlySecurityManager
> java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: Exception
> java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make field
> private java.security.ProtectionDomain[]
> java.security.AccessControlContext.context

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Alguien sabe que puede estar pasando?

Saludos.

Comment: Tu traza está incompleta, normalmente después de eso dice la versión de Java y menciona le paquete que debe ser abierto, por ejemplo java.base, te recomiendo agregar la traza completa para que podamos ayudarte

Comment: Gracias Ruslan López, aqui tienes la traza completa.

Comment: con qué estás construyendo tu aplicación? Maven, gradle, ant, Ivy, Leningen, Bazel, etc

Comment: La estoy construyendo con Maven.

Answer (score 0):

Como te lo menciona la traza de error

> module java.base does not "opens java.security" to unnamed module

así que toca abrir java.security para los módulos sin nombre agregando la siguiente opción

```
-J--add-opens=java.base/java.security=ALL-UNNAMED
```

Si usas algún sistema de construcción se puede especificar allí para ahorrarte tener que agregar eso en tu configuración cada que ejecutes o en la línea de comandos.

Por ejemplo en [maven](/questions/tagged/maven), en el plugin de la fase que haya fallado se puede agregar la siguiente configuración

```
 <configuration>
     <argLine>
         --add-opens=java.base/java.security=ALL-UNNAMED
     </argLine>
   </configuration>
```

En el caso de [gradle](/questions/tagged/gradle) busca en tus plugins sus opciones de configuración para los argumentos a la [jvm](/questions/tagged/jvm), por ejemplo en la tarea test quedaría algo así

```
tasks.test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
    jvmArgs = listOf("--add-opens=java.base/java.security=ALL-UNNAMED")
}
```

### ¿Por qué pasa esto?

Es una consecuencia de usar librerías que no fueron hechas con versiones modernas de Java, pues a partir de Java 9 se agrega el sistema de módulos Jigsaw y para hacerlo retro-compatible las librerías creadas antes se ponían en un módulo sin nombre que por razones de seguridad no tiene acceso al módulo llamado `java.base`

Comment: Disculpa esto que me pones "-J--add-opens=java.base/java.security=ALL-UNNAMED" ¿lo pongo al ejecutar el comando de maven como parámetro de la instrucción? Muchas gracias.

Comment: si estás corriendo como `java-jar` solo lo agregas al final, si no en el plugin de maven que usas para compilar y correr le agregas esas líneas de configuración

Comment: Muchas gracias, disculpa que no contestara en dos días. Un saludo.

Comment: Hola de nuevo, me da error, dice que no reconoce la opción: + echo deploy_wildfly
deploy_wildfly
[Pipeline] tool
[Pipeline] sh
+ mvn wildfly:deploy -J--add-opens=java.base/java.security=ALL-UNNAMED
Unable to parse command line options: Unrecognized option: -J--add-opens=java.base/java.security=ALL-UNNAMED

Comment: Lo que quiero crear es un war. ¿Pongo el pipeline? ¿Me podrías comentar que es lo que tengo que configurar en jenkins y en maven? Un saludo.

Comment: Jenkins tiene un campo llamado Java Options , allí es donde se debe agregar `--add-opens=java.base/java.security=ALL-UNNAMED`