# module java.base does not "opens java.util" to unnamed module

Tags: java, test, cucumber

Quisiera saber si alguien mas ha tenido este error o alguno parecido al intentar instalar o construir su proyecto maven con el comando "mvn install / mvn clean install":

> Unable to make field private transient java.util.NavigableMap java.util.TreeSet.m accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.util" to unnamed module @29617475

esto no pasaba hasta hace poco, se hizo una actualizacion al proyecto con nuevos metodos, pero nada fuera de lugar, luego de eso empezo con este error cuando la gente intentaba instalar su proyecto con el comando especificado, a continuación dejare el error mas detallado, dice que es por un plugin pero es demasiado raro ya que el plugin siempre ha funcionado bien.

> [WARNING] Error injecting: com.trivago.cluecumber.CluecumberReportPlugin
> com.google.inject.ProvisionException: Unable to provision, see the following errors:
>
> 1. Error injecting constructor, java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make field private transient java.util.NavigableMap java.util.TreeSet.m accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.util" to unnamed module @29617475
>    at com.trivago.cluecumber.rendering.pages.renderers.AllScenariosPageRenderer.(Unknown Source)
>    at org.eclipse.sisu.wire.LocatorWiring
>    while locating com.trivago.cluecumber.rendering.pages.renderers.AllScenariosPageRenderer annotated with interface org.eclipse.sisu.inject.TypeArguments$Implicit
>    at org.eclipse.sisu.wire.LocatorWiring
>    while locating com.trivago.cluecumber.rendering.pages.renderers.AllScenariosPageRenderer
>    for the 6th parameter of com.trivago.cluecumber.rendering.TemplateEngine.(Unknown Source)
>    at org.eclipse.sisu.wire.LocatorWiring
>    while locating com.trivago.cluecumber.rendering.TemplateEngine annotated with interface org.eclipse.sisu.inject.TypeArguments$Implicit
>    at org.eclipse.sisu.wire.LocatorWiring
>    while locating com.trivago.cluecumber.rendering.TemplateEngine
>    for the 1st parameter of com.trivago.cluecumber.rendering.ReportGenerator.(Unknown Source)
>    at org.eclipse.sisu.wire.LocatorWiring
>    while locating com.trivago.cluecumber.rendering.ReportGenerator annotated with interface org.eclipse.sisu.inject.TypeArguments$Implicit
>    at org.eclipse.sisu.wire.LocatorWiring
>    while locating com.trivago.cluecumber.rendering.ReportGenerator
>    for the 7th parameter of com.trivago.cluecumber.CluecumberReportPlugin.(Unknown Source)
>    while locating com.trivago.cluecumber.CluecumberReportPlugin

Intente actualizando el plugin pero el error persiste, por ende no se que sea, los metodos no son complejos por ende tampoco creo que sean el detonante, se los agredeceria mucho si me pudieran indicar como indagar mas en el error.

Comment: tal vez te ayude mi respuesta: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/607932/342

Comment: @RuslanLópez te lo agradezco mucho.